# Ruby on Rails: Splitting out lat and long from

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code:

```
include Geokit::Geocoders
res=MultiGeocoder.geocode('100 Spear st, San Francisco, CA')
puts res.ll
```

the result of this would be something like this:
37.7922379,-122.3939656

I need to be able to grab the lat and long values individually.

So, 
lat = something
long = something

I think this works?

```
res=MultiGeocoder.geocode(params[:street], params[:city], params[:state])
latLongString = res.ll
latLongArray = latLongString.split(',')
lat = latLongArray[0]
long = latLongArray[1]
```

I am not sure of the best Ruby code for this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
lat, lng = res.ll.split(",")
```